# Passing PHP variable to FLEX and enforcing that variable as a Nick in the script shown

Tags: php, apache-flex

Hey there I'm in deep trouble as I don't know a bit of FLEX. The code pasted below is from the Cirrus Sample Application (RTMFP).

I have the PHP variable $user->data['username']; which I need to set as the username. Can someone please help me pass this variable into the FLEX code and connect with it versus manually entering a username of choice and then clicking connect.

I think I got the first part figured out:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet --> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<?php 
    @ $Name = $user->data['username'];
?> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var swfVersionStr = ""; 
    var xiSwfUrlStr = ""; 
    var flashvars = {}; 
    flashvars.Name = "<?php echo $Name; ?>" 
    var params = {}; 
    params.quality = "high"; 
    params.bgcolor = "#ffffff"; 
    params.allowscriptaccess = "sameDomain"; 
    var attributes = {}; 
    attributes.id = "FlashVarTest"; 
    attributes.name = "FlashVarTest"; 
    attributes.align = "middle"; 
    swfobject.embedSWF( 
        "FlashVarTest.swf", "flashContent", 
        "100%", "100%", 
        swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
        flashvars, params, attributes); 
    swfobject.createCSS("#flashContent", "display:block;text-align:left;"); 
</script> 
</head> 
<body > 
    <div id="flashContent"> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I'm clueless on how to pass it to the Name field and have it autoconnect since I don't know FLEX. The source is too long for stackoverflow: http://pastebin.com/b0sFySYs

```
   <!-- Login pane -->
            <s:HGroup includeIn="LoginNotConnected" verticalAlign="middle">
                    <s:Label text="User Name: " color="0xffffff"/>
                    <s:TextInput id="userNameInput" width="80" enter="onConnect()"/>
                    <s:Button label="CONNECT" click="onConnect()" enabled="{userNameInput.text.length > 0}" styleName="buttonStyle"/>
            </s:HGroup>
            <s:HGroup includeIn="LoginConnecting" verticalAlign="middle">
                    <s:Label text="Connecting to {connectUrl}" color="0xffffff"/>
                    <s:Button label="CANCEL" click="onDisconnect()" styleName="buttonStyle"/>
            </s:HGroup>
            <s:HGroup includeIn="LoginConnected, CallReady, CallCalling, CallRinging, CallEstablished, CallFailed" verticalAlign="middle">
                    <s:Label text="Connected as {userNameInput.text}" color="0xffffff"/>
                    <s:Button label="DISCONNECT" click="onDisconnect()" styleName="buttonStyle"/>
            </s:HGroup>
            <s:HGroup includeIn="LoginDisconnecting">
                    <s:Label text="Disconnecting from {connectUrl}" color="0xffffff"/>
            </s:HGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is send the user/nickname in PHP to flex at the moment you are generating the embed code of your flex application. That can be done via the flashVars.

Then in your `init()` function you need to check if that variable has been supplied. If so, set `username.input.text` to that supplied value, and directly call `onConnect()` from the init function.

You *will* have to learn a bit of flex (Actionscript). Stackoverflow is not a 'please code this for me site'...

Comment: Yes I understand and respect that. I was just hoping for a random act of kindness.

Comment: I see you have done the first part. However I wonder what the @ does in your php tag and where $user is coming from. Maybe you snipped out a bit? That is ok, if you at least view your page source and check the usename is indeed being echoed out. TIP: Change `"<?php echo $Name; ?>"` into `<?php echo json_encode($Name); ?>` (without quotes) for proper js escaping.

Comment: Now what you still need to do is edit your `init()` function in your .as file. (And don't forget you need to recompile your .swf afterwards. You are aware, are you not?) Have your init function read out the flashVars and check if `Name` is given. If so, put it in the `username.input.text` and call `onConnect()`